# Vi Error while making git commit

Tags: git, vim, git-commit

I am attempting to make a git commit. I run the command `git commit` and vim opens up. I type in my commit message, and when I execute the `:wq` command, I get the following error:

> error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'. Please supply the
>   message using either -m or -F option.

Any idea how I can figure out what the problem is?

Comment: did it solved your problem ?

Comment: It did. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix this problem change your git editor path

```
git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim
```

[SOURCE](http://tooky.co.uk/there-was-a-problem-with-the-editor-vi-git-on-mac-os-x/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to recover the commit message, you can look in [`.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`](https://book.git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit-codeGITDIRCOMMITEDITMSGcode).

> This file contains the commit message of a commit in progress. If `git
>   commit` exits due to an error before creating a commit, any commit
>   message that has been provided by the user (e.g., in an editor
>   session) will be available in this file, but will be overwritten by
>   the next invocation of `git commit`.